# Send event and data to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to have one bash script wait on a piece of data from another.
Is there a native Linux way that I can accomplish that, preferably without the use of files which can become stale?

Comment: What sort of data?  Is a pipe appropriate:  `another-script | one-bash-script`?

Comment: you don't have to chain them either with named pipes, check for `mkfifo`

Comment: Chaining won't work.  It's actually a complex service dependency in runit.  But it's not enough to check if the other service is running.  It outputs data that the other is dependant on.

Comment: I'm looking at mkfifo now.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this in the end was to use fifo pipes.

e.g. source.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -p "pipe" ]; then
  mkfifo -m 0600 "pipe"
fi

echo "hello world" > "pipe"
```

dest.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -p "pipe" ]; then
  mkfifo -m 0600 "pipe"
fi

MYVAR=$(<"pipe")
echo $MYVAR
```

Because writing and reading blocks, each script will not proceed until either the data is sent or read in.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the [Subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) in the scripting? Though I personally do not have any experience with it thought you might want to try other approaches.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I am also very much interested in this particular questions.

Comment: I did, I'll post an answer.